# Creación de csv con php ¿Cómo puedo eliminar el espacio que se me genera por defecto?

Tags: php, csv

estoy realizando un trabajo con js, html, php y mysql
Resulta que debo crear con consultas una tabla en formato .CSV la cual se debe cargar a un gráfico. Para cargar los datos utilizo php que me devuelve el .CSV en forma de descarga, el problema entra en que cuando quiero utilizar los datos resulta que el formato no es correcto puesto que hace dos saltos de linea que se mal interpretan al ser llamados por mi gráfico realizado en js. Seguramente haya alguna sentencia para mover lo puesto un poco más arriba, dejo el código PHP.

```
    <?php
//DB details
$dbHost     = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName     = 'grafico';

//Create connection and select DB
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if($db->connect_error){
    die("Unable to connect database: " . $db->connect_error);
}
?>


<?php

//Guarda la base de datos
$query = $db->query("SELECT Semana, Ingresos FROM datos ORDER BY Semana DESC");

if($query->num_rows > 0){
    $delimiter = ",";
    $filename = "datos_" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";
    
    //crea el espacio de memoria donde se aloja
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
    
    //Pone los nombre de columna en el csv
    $fields = array('Semana', 'Ingresos');
    fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);
    
    //Da un output para cada fila de datos, da formato a la linea como un csv
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $status = ($row['Semana'] == '0')?'Inactive':'Active';
        $lineData = array($row['Semana'], $row['Ingresos']);
        fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
        }
    
    //move back to beginning of file
    fseek($f, 0);
    
    //set headers to download file rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');
    
    //output all remaining data on a file pointer
    fpassthru($f);
}
exit;

?>
```

Este es el output que me suelta de los datos al descargar, lo único que necesito es que no aparezcan esos espacios vacíos. ¿Alguna idea?

[image: Este es el output que me suelta de los datos al descargar]

Comment: Los espacios que aparecen en el archivo son los espacios que dejaste entre `?>


<?php`, simplemente borra esas lineas y listo

Comment: Si me sirvió muchas gracias